# Runtime Exception in some devices in Playstore Pre-launch Report

Tags: android, email, runtimeexception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure from system
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1547)
at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.execStartActivity(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:501)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4283)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:68)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4230)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:751)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4567)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4535)
at packagename.feedback.sendEmail(feedback.java:312)
at packagename.feedback.onClick(feedback.java:324)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10814)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.loopAndInterrogate(Interrogator.java:148)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:465)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:421)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.injectMotionEvent(UiControllerImpl.java:235)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:140)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:123)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap.sendSingleTap(Tap.java:170)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap.access$100(Tap.java:31)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap(Tap.java:47)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:136)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:356)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:248)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.access$100(ViewInteraction.java:63)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:153)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1670532 bytes
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3129)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1540)
... 38 more
```

The pre-launch report shows issues with 3 devices with the RuntimeException. This occurs when I try to send mail. But the other devices has no problems with this. The devices are Galaxy S7 Edge, LG G6 and Galaxy J7(2016). Any one has idea about this?

This is my sendmail() function.

```
 public void sendEmail(String body) {

    StringBuilder finalBody = new StringBuilder(body);

    if (withInfo) {
        finalBody.append(deviceInfo);
        finalBody.append(SystemLog.extractLogToString());
    }

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("*/*");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getAppLabel(this) + " Feedback");

    if (realPath!=null){
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + realPath);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    }

    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{emailId});
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, finalBody.toString());

    startActivity(Utils.createEmailOnlyChooserIntent(this, emailIntent, getString(R.string.send_feedback_two)));

}
```